# Unknown request in nginx log

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn, amazon-lightsail

I have been getting some request to my nginx server that has been hosted on the AWS Light sail. While some requests doesn't make any sense, while one request points out to a github page of a Mass IP scanner. Does that mean someone is trying to get access to the server via the open port

```
44.224.22.196 - - [24/Nov/2019:12:33:38 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xD2\x01\x00\x00\xCE\x03\x03Jb8\x0B\x82\xDD\xB6i\x17\xFC\x5C\x9F\xB7.\xB8~(p\xD1\xD6M'\xC3\x8E8\xB7\x99\x8D\xA6'\xB9l\x00\x00b\xC00\xC0,\xC0/\xC0+\x00\x9F\x00\x9E\xC02\xC0.\xC01\xC0-\x00\xA5\x00\xA1\x00\xA4\x00\xA0\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 182 "-" "-"
44.224.22.196 - - [24/Nov/2019:12:33:38 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xD2\x01\x00\x00\xCE\x03\x03\xC8\xC6X1kja{\xAF\xFA7\xBD_\x85?0\x86\xF6\xE8\xE2\xCEZT\xFA\xA0\xF1\x99\x9DV\x18\x01\x17\x00\x00b\xC00\xC0,\xC0/\xC0+\x00\x9F\x00\x9E\xC02\xC0.\xC01\xC0-\x00\xA5\x00\xA1\x00\xA4\x00\xA0\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 182 "-" "-"
44.224.22.196 - - [24/Nov/2019:12:33:39 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xD2\x01\x00\x00\xCE\x03\x03!\xD1bc\xF6e\xF3\xD3\x1D;\xA0\xAAc\x08\x80\xF0\x066\x9C\xEATu\xB7\xA9\x89\x96Z\xB8\x83?q3\x00\x00b\xC00\xC0,\xC0/\xC0+\x00\x9F\x00\x9E\xC02\xC0.\xC01\xC0-\x00\xA5\x00\xA1\x00\xA4\x00\xA0\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 182 "-" "-"
```

While the above request doesn't make any sense, the next is usually the gitub repo

```
173.249.51.194 - - [24/Nov/2019:13:08:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)"
159.65.188.111 - - [24/Nov/2019:13:37:40 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)"
159.65.188.111 - - [24/Nov/2019:13:37:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 444 0 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)"
```

Am using the nginx to proxy forward to the gunicorn running on another port

Comment: Most likely this is automated scanning by (malicious) bots looking for vulnerabilities on your server. The first snippet shows a request to your server with a series of control characters. Make sure you have a firewall running and keep your server patched to mitigate these attacks.

Comment: Those strange requests are the hacker trying to hide their request data by using UTF-32 (Unicode) data. I did not check each byte, but that is what the data stream appears to be.  The second set of requests is the `masscan` penetration testing tool which is part of Kali Linux Tools. You have a "Script Kiddie" playing around on the Internet trying to find vulnerable sites.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, Do you think i should be worried and take any mitigation measure to prevent such request

Comment: The answer depends. You will be attacked by hackers 24 hours a day. If you understand security and have implemented patched and updated systems, in general I don't worry. The answer is in the details of your software, your system and how everything is managed.